# Can i use Masstransit to consume message as string/byte array?

Tags: .net, rabbitmq, masstransit

I have used Masstransit before in simple manner. Now I need to use RabbitMQ to receive messages as string/byte array. Again wont be knowing the message types before hand so just want to consume messages without knowing its types.

Just to consume string/byte array messages is it better to use Masstransit ?

Thank you in advance and appreciate the answer.

Chandra

Comment: MassTransit works on types, messages should be types. You'd need to build your own message deserializer that could turn those bytes into types. Otherwise, you're just grinding your gears.